# Returning a max integer value from a pandas list of string numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this where df['value_list'] has `dtype` object:

```
                     value_list  
0             ['200000.00', '100.00', '25.00']                 
1                       ['860000.00']                          
2                  ['148000.00', '25.00']
```

I want a new column `max_value` which will be the max integer numerical value of the string numbers inside this list. So expected results for above:

```
                     value_list                              max_value
0             ['200000.00', '100.00', '25.00']                 200000
1                       ['860000.00']                          860000
2                  ['148000.00', '25.00']                      148000
```

What I did:

```
# covert strings to numerical values
df['value_list'] = df['value_list'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
# get max values from list and if list is empty temporarily assign -1
df['max_value'] = df['value_list'].apply(lambda x: max(x) if len(x) >= 1 else -1)
df['max_value'] = df['max_value'].apply(lambda x: round(float(x)) if x != -1 else None)
```

Which seems to have worked but I didn't actually get the max values. The results I got:

```
                     value_list                              max_value
0             ['200000.00', '100.00', '25.00']                  25
1                       ['860000.00']                          860000
2                  ['148000.00', '25.00']                       25
```

Is there a better and more correct way to do this? Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach:

```
import pandas as pd

# input toy data 
df = pd.DataFrame([[['200000.00', '100.00', '25.00']],
                   [['860000.00']],
                   [['148000.00', '25.00']]], columns=["value_list"])

df["max_value"] = df["value_list"].apply(lambda x: max(float(e) for e in x))
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
                   value_list  max_value
0  [200000.00, 100.00, 25.00]   200000.0
1                 [860000.00]   860000.0
2          [148000.00, 25.00]   148000.0
```

If you have empty lists and want to return `-1`, just do:

```
df["max_value"] = df["value_list"].apply(lambda x: max(float(e) for e in x) if x else -1)
```

Comment: or as list comprehension: `df['max_value'] = [max(float(e) for e in x)) for x in df['value_list']]`

Comment: @amnesic I think you need to add a realistic example of the DataFrame, one that can be copied and pasted in a Python script... Given the error that you got it seems that the values of the column are strings, as opposed to list

Comment: @amnesic Updated the answer to handle the case of the empty list (returning -1)